# How do you assign a variable to a form from earlier php code to post to next php page?

Tags: php

I am making a site that collects user comments via a submission form and then outputs them all onto a page where they can be rated from 1-10. I'm having trouble with the rating system part.

I have a form with radio buttons for my rating which sends by post the value via the 'SendRating.php'. I also want to send a previously used variable which is the 'id' that is tied to the particular comment and the particular rating. I have tried to use a hidden input to do this but I cannot seem to get the syntax correct and whatever I try I seem to get an error.

I will show you both php files I have:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("host","me","pwd","base");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $query= "SELECT  id, comment, date_made, rating FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 15";
    $result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $date=$row['date_made'];
        $id=$row['id'];
        $num_id=intVal($id);
        $current=$row['rating'];

        echo '<div id="text" onpaste="return false"; oncut="return false"; readonly>';
        echo '<div id="text2">';
        echo "Submitted: ";
        echo date('l jS F Y H:i:s ',strtotime($date));echo '&nbsp;'; echo '&nbsp;'; 
        echo '&nbsp;'; echo "No: ";  echo $row['id']; 
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<br>'; 
        echo nl2br($row['comment']);
        echo '<br>'; echo '<br>'; 
        echo '</a>';

        //FOOT
        echo '<div >'; 
        echo '<form id="radio" name="input_rating" action="SendRating.php"     method="post" >';
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'$id'" >';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating"  onclick="this.form.submit()" value="1">1';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="2">2';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="3">3';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="4">4';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating"     onclick="this.form.submit()" value="5">5';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="6">6';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="7">7';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="8">8';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="9">9';
        echo '<input  id="radio" type="radio" name="rating" onclick="this.form.submit()" value="10">10';

        echo '&nbsp;'; echo '&nbsp;'; echo '&nbsp;'; echo  "Rating: ";
        echo '&nbsp';
        echo  "$current";
        echo '</form>';

        echo '</div>';

        //END FOOT

         echo '</div>'; 
         echo '<p></p>';
    }
?>
```

The form action is processed by the following (or would be if it was all working):

```
<?php
    $con2=mysqli_connect("host","me","pwd","base");

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con2))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        $value=$_POST['rating'];
        $id=$_POST['id'];

    mysqli_query  ($con2, "UPDATE table SET totalraters = totalraters + 1 WHERE id='$id' ");
    mysqli_query  ($con2, "UPDATE table SET ratingsum = ratingsum + '$value' WHERE id='$id' ");

    $query2 = mysqli_query ($con2, "SELECT FROM table ratingsum, totalraters WHERE id = '$id' ");
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con2, $query2);
    $row2 =mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

    $ratingsum=$row2['ratingsum']; 
    $totalraters=$row2['totalraters'];
    $current = $ratingsum/$ratingtotal;
    mysqli_query ($con2, "INSERT INTO table rating VALUE '$current' WHERE id='$id' ");

    include ('/index.html')
?>
```

The include page should take the user back to the start page where the rating is updated.

ratingsum is the total added up of the ratings given and totalraters is the number of people who have rated. $current should be the average which gives the current rating.

The line I'm having trouble with at the moment is

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'$id'" >';
```

I can't seem to get the id from one place to the other to be used in further queries. I get a syntax error for this line. 
Help gratefully received and believe I have tried everything but the correct solution!!
Please use procedural because I am new and can't understand object oriented at all...it makes my head hurt ;-)

Comment: What error message are you getting and which line is causing the error?

Comment: Your PHP would be a lot prettier and full of far less echos if you structure it according to the top example at the bottom of the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119083/php-tutorial-that-is-security-accuracy-and-maintainability-conscious

Comment: Thankyou Patashu I think I understand and it should neaten it up.

Comment: @Nigel The error said that the syntax was incorrect. I used the top method by Ivan below and it fixed that. I now have a different error. mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/public_html/SendRating.php on line 21

Comment: Which line in the code is line 21?

Comment: @Nigel Line 21:$row2 =mysqli_fetch_array($result2);

Answer (score 1):

This is done this way:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" >';
```

See those dotes between string and variable, they say to merge those.
This one will be incorrect:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" >';
```

because single quotes ignore variables. Thanks to `michi` and `lemondrop` for a tip!

Comment: your 2nd example won't work because of single quotes. `echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\"$id\" />` will do however.

Comment: @michi why single quotes would do something bad? I have never seen any harm from them... In case they do and I have missed smth you may just swap single and double quotes :)

Comment: @Ivan I thought they completely ignore vars inside them.

Comment: Yeah, right I bag my pardon, now I got 1 step up. Thank you guys!

Comment: Double quotes evaluate variables within. Single quotes won't. So if `$foo = 'bar';` then `echo "dive $foo";` will output `dive bar` but `echo 'dive $foo';` will output `dive $foo`.

Comment: Thankyou very much that fixed the specific error message for that line!!  My next horror: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/public_html/SendRating.php on line 21

Comment: @Ivan: see other's comments on single vs. double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

To improve on @ivan's answer.. yes he is correct but he has given invalid code that might give unexpected outputs/errors.. His:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $id . '" >';
```

You might encounter a `Notice: Undefined Index $id`  so it's best to handle the error thrown, the best way I can think of, is to drop out of your PHP tags when you wish to print HTML:

```
?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="$id" >
<?php
 ....
```

But then, handle a POSSIBLE undefined index (whilst still out of your PHP tags)

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php if (isset($id)){ echo $id; } ?>">
```

This will tell PHP to output id only if it's set, which will then minimize the possible undefined index error.